# KnockoutJS - Show different template if no data returned

Tags: knockout.js

Using KnockoutJS with jQuery templates, is it possible to render a different template or html string if no data is returned:

Currently I'm binding a table to the data as below:

```
<tbody data-bind='template: {name: "PriceTemplate", foreach: prices}'>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You could control that in your ajax callback: if no result, don't try to refresh the table but display a message somewhere or hide the table or anything else.

Comment: Fair enough, I was hoping there might be a knockoutJS specific answer to this.

Comment: In Jquery tmpl, you can also use {{if}} but I prefer having very simple templates without intelligence in them in general.

Answer (score 0):

I agree whit @mandubian about keeping your templates simple.  When they don't work, they are difficult to troubleshoot.

On [knockoutjs template-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), Steve Sanderson shows a way to dynamically switch templates.  For your example, you could use something like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/4tHUr/1/